# how to define url path to access child projects from main project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, web

I have 3 projects- Main Project, Project A and Project B. I have added reference to both A & B inside Main project. Now, if i make ajax call from Main project to say Project A (web service project), how would my url look like? I have tried using localhost, but i ran into CORS issue. So, is there any solution for that? thnks.

```
var url = '../ProjectA/someService.asmx?op=Action';
```

Comment: Why do you need the URL? As you have the references in main project, you can call the methods directly...

Comment: @Vimalan: well i was trying to call web service method using ajax call.

Comment: Why not remove the references and just install them as 3 separate web applications under the same domain? This sounds like it would fit your use case

Comment: @EMI: so if i create 3 sepearte web applicatons under same solution, how can i enable same domain?

Comment: It's a question of how you deploy it. If deploying to IIS, each project would be deployed to a web application underneath a single web site. For development in visual studio, IIS express will probably not let you do this which is inconvenient. But you may be able to work around it by having project A and project B send Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header for DEBUG builds and removing it for production builds. This will prevent the CORS issue you described

Comment: @EMI: well i'm using visual studio development server 9.0. i did tried adding CORS setting inside web.config in web service project. But, i don't get back response header with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.